# How do Eigen::Map default template arguments work?

Tags: c++, eigen

This is most likely not specfific to Eigen, but this is the first time I'm seeing it and wonedered how it works.

In the [definition of Eigen::Map](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Map_8h_source.html) there are 3 template arguments: `<typename PlainObjectType, int MapOptions, typename StrideType>`.

No defaults are set, however as can be seen in [these examples](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) the last two arguments are not specified. For example, we can simply write `Map<Matrix3i>(array)`.

Am I missing something? Is this specific to this case or more generally in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default options are defined in a header [`ForwardDeclarations.h`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/669323b59b02/Eigen/src/Core/util/ForwardDeclarations.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ForwardDeclarations.h-119):

```
template<typename MatrixType, 
         int MapOptions=Unaligned,
         typename StrideType = Stride<0,0>
>
class Map;
```

(newlines added for readability)

Comment: Nice catch, completely forgot to check if there were any forward declarations somewhere else. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities about it. The first one, more trivial, is giving default argument in template declaration instead of definition. Perhaps somwhere in library header there is something like this:

```
template<typename PlainObjectType,
     int MapOptions = <some default options>,
     typename StrideType = <some default type>> 
class Map;
```

The second possibility is [partial template specialization, about which You can read at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)